# I can't see the close votes on my own question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions

I want to reopen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774887/how-to-validate-a-mathematical-expression. But no matter how hard I try, it is never reopened.

The close reason is the old: "what have you tried" reason, I included some code but nothing happened.
and I can't see the reason why it is not, I have more than 250 reputation but I can't see the close reasons.

Note that when I asked the question I wasn't searching for code, I wanted a method to solve my problem.
It was sufficient to say: you can use the `preg_split` function.

I just want to know the exact reason behind closing my question so I can improve it. I've read the comments but I don't see anything helpful at this point.

So because I can't see the close votes on my question, could someone view these votes and tell me what should I improve?

Comment: I recognize a lot of those names from the PHP room. It is my opinion that the best thing you can do is talk to them - all those people are a) very helpful and b) would likely vote to reopen your answer if you have a good reason to reopen it.

Comment: I don't see anyone of them in the chat room right now. I will try later.

Comment: @user689 `But no matter how hard I try, it is never reopened.`.... I hate to use this phase, but *what have you tried* to get it reopened?  It was edited once after being place on hold.  That would have put it into the reopen queue, but obviously wasn't reopened.  I don't see a meta question asking about why your post was closed.  This is the closest one I could find and you aren't really asking about why, and it is over a month after the post was closed.  Did you vote to reopen it yourself after you improved it?  Did you seek out other opinions?  It almost looks like you tried once & gave up

Comment: @psubsee2003 I don't want to keep editing my question because it annoys other user and I have no clue why it is kept closed after I clarified my point. I tried searching for a mathmatical parser or any library to do what I want but I couldn't find any.

Comment: @user689 not, that's fine... my point was you said you keep trying to get it reopen and I was trying to understand what you did as there aren't lot of obvious signs of attempts.  If you really want to understandin, I think asking a meta question "How can fix my question to get it reopened" would be the most direct and appropriate way.

Comment: @user689 However, if you do that you may expose yourself to downvotes.  If people disagree it should be reopened, you might get downvotes on the meta post, and it could attract more downvotes to your SO post as well.  Unfortunately MEta is a double edge sword, but can be a useful tool

Comment: @psubsee2003 thanks right now I will try as hard as I can to get this reopened, if it wasn't I will ask this on meta. I don't care about points, I'm here to learn and not to collect points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "view close vote" privilege allows you to see the number of close votes on your post **before** it is closed, as well as allow you to vote to close your own post and (and also offers the same privileges for reopening as well).  That's it, there's nothing more to it.

It sounds like you are hoping that you can see individual pieces of information from the voters to get insight into why they voted to close your post, but from the perspective of a close voter, the only insight that we can offer outside of leaving a comment is the text of the close reason, which you have already:

> "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist" – Marcin Orlowski, Madara Uchiha, Jeremy, tereško, hakre

Although you appear to be aware already, it is worth mentioning for future reference, that this close reason was removed about the same time your post was closed because it was often misused or misinterpreted.

---

For your specific post, even though it isn't what you are asking here, it seems to be what you are interested in understanding.  As I mentioned above, except for the text of the close reason that everyone selected, the only other way to provide feedback on why you are close and how to improve is via a comment.

You do have a few comments explaining why the post was closed, including one from one of the commenters.

> Sounds like meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem to me. – Neikos Dec 25 '13 at 16:55
>
> You need to develope your own parser, or try to find a one at web. In any case, this can't be solved just with a couple of lines of JS. – Teemu Dec 25 '13 at 17:04
>
> "Or generally how to solve this problem." - This starts with looking for duplicates and a little research. Normally this involves just using a library that does the job for you. Those do exist. So it does not start with looking for a regex (and the answer you did accept isn't pure regex either btw). – hakre Dec 25 '13 at 17:26

I don't know PHP or javascript and even in a language I am familiar with, I wouldn't try to do what you are attempting, so I have little insight to the specific or general challenges, but my interpretation of the comments there is you are going about it the wrong way and regex is not the solution.  It almost sounds like a 3rd party library is your only solution and not trying to write your own parser from scratch.

Assuming this is the case, then there is probably little that can be done, unless someone with more language familiarity and offer you specific insight into your post.

Comment: The comments were there before an answer was posted to prove that this is possible. Also, I've edited the part of my question that was causing this confusion: I was trying to solve this by using regex which seems impossible. The answer that is posted is exactly what I want, I just don't want the question to get deleted.

Comment: @user689 ok, but that really wasn't part of my answer, just some meta commentary on your post since you seemed to want some insight.  Your question was "why can't I view close votes" and the answer is "you can, but it doesn't mean what you seem to think it means"

Comment: @user689 I'm looking for the reference now, but your question *should* be protected from the automated deletion because it has an upvoted answer, but I'm looking for a reference now to confirm

Comment: @user689 Here's the [criteria for automatic deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/182513).  Of course this won't prevent manual deletion.